# QGIS not exporting JSON to GeoJSON format

Tags: qgis, geojson, json

My PostgreSQL/PostGIS table have a JSON column, how to export it as GeoJSON `properties` to QGIS?

That is, I have a PostgreSQL connection at QGIS and **it is reading all other tables, except this one that have a JSON colummn**. It is  possible to read JSON column at QGIS?

### NOTES

Community say that "QGIS was born for PostgGIS"... Seems a bug because JSON  good support exist since PostgreSQL v9.3, and GeoJSON is used by QGIS since 2016 or before, it is not a strange object...

If it is not a bug, and it is not an expected QGIS feature, a workaround is perhaps to create a SQL VIEW where each line is a GeoJSON to be exported to QGIS... I am testing  "generic VIEW template" solution, using [`jsonb_populate_record` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Hello @underdark, sorry the delay to see comments and answers... I edited but to later, only after answer. Well, good answer, explain how to make all as FeatureCollection, etc.

Answer (score 5):

No need for QGIS here. Imagining you have a recent PostgreSQL and PostGIS 3+ (because of function [ST_AsGeoJSON](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html)), in the command line, you can use the following

```
psql -t test_postgis3 <<EOF > /tmp/out.geojson
select json_build_object(
    'type', 'FeatureCollection',
    'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(t.*)::json)
    )
from ( values (1, 'one', '{"foo": 9, "bar": 6}'::jsonb, 'POINT(1 1)'::geometry),
              (2, 'two', '{"foo": 4, "bar": 5}'::jsonb, 'POINT(2 2)'),
              (3, 'three', '{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}'::jsonb, 'POINT(3 3)')
     ) as t(id, name, nested_prop, geom);
\q
EOF
```

We use here psql with `-t` option to say tuple deactivated e.g output will not contain anything than the query (no column name). We connect here to database test_postgis3 (we suppose PostGIS extension 3 is loaded). Then we use a HERE document (works on Unix, otherwise, put your query in a separated file) and redirect output to /tmp/out.geojson

You may prefer put in a SQL file `query.sql` with below content

```
select json_build_object(
    'type', 'FeatureCollection',
    'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(t.*)::json)
    )
from ( values (1, 'one', '{"foo": 9, "bar": 6}'::jsonb, 'POINT(1 1)'::geometry),
              (2, 'two', '{"foo": 4, "bar": 5}'::jsonb, 'POINT(2 2)'),
              (3, 'three', '{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}'::jsonb, 'POINT(3 3)')
     ) as t(id, name, nested_prop, geom);
```

and run the following

```bsh
psql -t test_postgis3 < /tmp/query.sql > /tmp/out.geojson
```

The above is a standalone sample, for real use, do use an SQL query like below

```
-- You may explicitly use column names in
-- SELECT * FROM your_table or do a geometry conversion to EPSG 4326
-- with ST_Transform(your_geom_col_name, 4326) AS your_geom_col_name
select json_build_object(
    'type', 'FeatureCollection',
    'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(t.*)::json)
    )
from ( SELECT * FROM your_table) as t
```

Inserting the following basic sample,

```
CREATE TABLE demo(
  id integer,
  name text,
  nested_prop jsonb,
  geom geometry(Point,4326)
);

INSERT INTO demo(id, name, nested_prop, geom)
values (1, 'one', '{"foo": 9, "bar": 6}'::jsonb, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)'), 4326)),
       (2, 'two', '{"foo": 4, "bar": 5}'::jsonb, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(2 2)'), 4326)),
       (3, 'three', '{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}'::jsonb, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(3 3)'),4326));
```

You will do the query below:

```sql
select json_build_object(
    'type', 'FeatureCollection',
    'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(t.*)::json)
    )
from ( SELECT * FROM demo) as t
```

We borrowed more or less http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/08/postgis-3-geojson.html but using `json_build_object` to create a GeoJSON FeatureCollection